# How to place <Login> component if I have nested all component inside Router

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, react-router-dom, outlet

I was not able to figure out where to place login so that:

- first default endpoint be `profile`
- second endpoint be `message`
- full page view on endpoint `/login`

```
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/message" element={ <Message /> } />
          <Route path="/" exact element={ <Profile /> } />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
```

```css
.App{
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: .5fr 2fr;
}
```

is there a proper way to manage or place the component?

Design:
[image]

- After one of the solution some component render multiple time :(

```
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

          <Route element={<NavBarLayout />}>
            <Route path="/message" element={<Message />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Profile />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
```

[image]

codesandbox.io link [project code](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-mayer-3xmf2e?file=/src/views/profile/Profile.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I see what you are asking for... you want to render a route for the login page that ***doesn't*** include the `NavBar` component. For this you use what are called [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes). Create a layout wrapper that includes the `NavBar` and an `Outlet` component for nested routes to be rendered into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavbarLayout = () => (
  <div className="Navbar">
    <NavBar />
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);
```

...

```
.App {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: .5fr 2fr;
}
```

...

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

      {/* 2-column layout with navbar */}
      <Route element={<NavbarLayout />}>
        <Route path="/message" element={<Message />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Profile />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Comment: @ullaskunder Do you think your could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue we could inspect and debug live? Or if it's hosted in a github repo the link to your repo so we can fork it for testing?

Comment: okk done link for the code https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-mayer-3xmf2e?file=/src/views/profile/Profile.js

Comment: @ullaskunder You were rendering an `Outlet` in your `NavBar` component (https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-mayer-3xmf2e?file=/src/navbar/NavBar.js:1635-1659). It seems your routes are duplicated into it. I don't think you need this `Outlet` at all since your routes are rendered in the other panel.

Answer (score 1):

You could do conditional rendering

```
if(!authenticated) {
        return(
            <LoginPage loginHandler={loginHandler} />
        )
    } else {
        return(
            <Router>
               <Navbar />
               ....
        )
```